# Classify data by value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form

```
low_bound   high_bound   name
0           10           'a'
10          20           'b'
20          30           'c'
30          40           'd'
40          50           'e'
```

I have a **very long** `pandas.Series` of the form:

```
value
5.7
30.4
21
35.1
```

I want to give to each value of the Series its corresponding name with respect to the low_bound/high_bound/name DataFrame.
Here is my expected result:

```
value         name
5.7           'a'
30.4          'd'
21            'c'
35.1          'd'
```

Indeed, 5.7 name is 'a' since 5.7 is between 0 and 10 excluded.

What would be the most efficient code? I know I can solve the problem by iterating through the Series, but maybe there is a quicker vectorial solution which is escaping me.

Note finally that my bounds can be custom and irregular. Here they are regular for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas has a method called `cut` that will do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"low": 0, "high": 10, "name": "a"},
        {"low": 10, "high": 20, "name": "b"},
        {"low": 20, "high": 30, "name": "c"},
        {"low": 30, "high": 40, "name": "d"},
        {"low": 40, "high": 50, "name": "e"},]

myDF = pd.DataFrame(data)

#data to be binned
mySeries = pd.Series([5.7, 30.4, 21, 35.1])

#create bins from original data
bins = list(myDF["high"])
bins.insert(0,0)

print pd.cut(mySeries, bins, labels = myDF["name"])
```

That will give you the following, which you can then put back into some dataframe or however you want to hold your data:

```
0    a
1    d
2    c
3    d
dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [a < b < c < d < e]
```

Depending on how irregular your bins are (and what you mean exactly by custom/irregular), you might have to resort to looping through the series. I can't think off the top of my head of a builtin that will handle this for you, especially given that it depends on the degree/type of irregularity in the bins.

Looping wise, this method will work if you have a lower and upper bound, regardless of "regularity":

```
for el in mySeries:
    print myDF["name"][(myDF["low"] < el) & (myDF["high"] > el)]
```

I appreciate that you might not want to loop through a huge series, but at least we're not manually indexing into the dataframe, which would probably make things even slower

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
buckets = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
buckets_name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

pd.cut(your_series, buckets , labels = buckets_name)
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler.